# Disabling the Automagic Property Name "Helpers" in Visual Studio / Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

How do I get rid of these bits highlighted in yellow that keep auto-appearing (like a codelens feature):
[image]

I just got a new computer so this is a fresh install of both VS and Resharper - I have been unable to determine which is responsible for this "feature", but I hate it.

Anyone know how to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ReSharper 2018.3-introduced feature called Inline Parameter Hints. In Visual Studio 2017, go to (your menu choices may differ slightly, but you'll get the idea...) **Tools** | **Options** | **ReSharper Ultimate** | **General** and click **Options**. From there you will see a screen similar to this:

[image]

You can customize the behavior of this feature there.